# Google no longer allows using WebView. What are the alternatives?

Tags: android, webview, google-play

The new [Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) state that it is no longer allowed to publish web browsers that are based on WebView:

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
>
> Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you
>   (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do
>   so)

I was thinking of developing a `WebView`-based web browser but now I see that this is no longer allowed.

Frankly, I find it insane to ask every website in existence for permission to display its content via a WebView based browser.

What are my options? Is there an alternative web kit that is as powerful as WebView?

Comment: The "primary functionality" of your browser is probably not to display *a* website is it?

Comment: Hi. Can you add the source link from where you got this information. It might be helpful to so many who don't know this new rule from Google.

Comment: The way that I read it... It doesn't say you can't develop a WebView based browser. It says you can't just wrap up a single site (that doesn't belong to you) in a WebView and call it an app.

Comment: That clause isn't about building a general purpose web browser using WebView - it's about making an app to wrap a specific website in a WebView.

Comment: @nEx.Software What if it wraps up 10 web sites? In a single app that is.

Comment: @iPhan Do those 10 sites belong to you, or do you have permission from the owner to wrap their sites in an 'app'? That's the main point of the clause... You can't just wrap up others' web property and call it an app.

Comment: @nEx.Software And if I use raw HTTP to display them and I don't use WebView, can I do that?

Comment: @iPhan There are certainly other Java based HTML/CSS rendering engines out there aside from just using the WebView, but I think if you get to that point, you're really just reaching for a way around this reasonable policy.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't say  you're not allowed to make a browser.

It says, that you're not allowed to make an app which merely is a WebView showing a website you do not own, and don't have permission from the owners to make.

That is, I am not allowed to make a GMail app, which merely is a WebView showing the GMail mobile website.

One reason could be, that such an app provides nothing that a bookmark wouldn't. Another reason could be, that such an app may seem to the end user to be affiliated with the website it's embedding. If the app then added adverts, crashed or provided some kind of negative user experience, this could reflect poorly on the website being embedded.

Comment: So if you have a better way of displaying Gmail, you are not allowed to do that? Isn't this in essence stifling creativity?

Comment: @iPhan: How're you being creative if all you're doing is packaging someone else's website into an app? You're free to make your own GMail app if you don't simply package the website and call it a day. (Provided it doesn't go against GMail's terms of service and all that.)

Comment: That's the point of creativity. You can't even envision it until the first one to create shows it to you. But looks like Google doesn't want this to happen.

Comment: Perhaps you could use all that creativity for creating something original as opposed to using it to try to find a way around this (pretty common sense) clause...

Comment: Long story short... If a site provides an API, and you have permission to use it, then by all means use it to create something better. Heck, you can even use a WebView to present it if you want. Maybe they'll even take notice and ask you to join their team if what you create is that much better. Just don't merely wrap their site in a WebView.

Answer (score 1):

You totally missed the point, if you are making app that displays some site that you don't own then some users of that site will use your app instead of simple browsing to get information from that site.

Let's say that site has 3 pages

1. -> 2. -> 3.

If you are showing page #3 from your app then users will not see ads from page 1. and 2. Which means that you are stealing that site's money.

And that's why you need permission from site owner.

Comment: I don't want to still any site's money. If someone doesn't write a web browser and only writes a browser add-on that filters ads, he is stilling site's money???

Comment: It seams that I explained above how that works. The point is that you can show that site fully (all 3 pages) and it is totally legal because you showing all content with all ads. But since most sites got dozens of pages like this you have to ask permission of particular site you are making app of.